# How to get Apex Class Members of an Apex Class in Salesforce?

Tags: apex

How can I get all methods and properties of an ApexClass?

I have tried the Toolkit API, but found no result.

Comment: Apex does not really support introspection, you could serialize the class as JSON and parse json to get the list of methods

Comment: What exactly you want.Can you please elaborate your requirement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In workbench, you can call the Toolkit API through REST Explorer.

`/services/data/v39.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+Id,Name,SymbolTable+From+ApexClass+where+Id='01pi0000007BW7c'`

The Toolkit response is a JSON Object.The JSON response contains a `SymbolTable` field that gives you all `constructors`, `interfaces`, `methods` and `variables` details.

[image]

From Apex you can do a similar REST call to the Toolkit API to get the same JSON Response. Make sure the Query is well formed and have no white spaces or else you will get 400 error.

```
String classID = '01pG0000003ou6c';
String baseUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v39.0/tooling/query/';
String query = '?q=Select+Id,Name,SymbolTable+From+ApexClass+where+Id=\'' + classID + '\'';
String endPoint = baseUrl+query;

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

req.setEndpoint(endPoint);
req.setMethod('GET');

Http h = new Http();
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
system.debug('@@'+res.getBody());
```